# Chart JS React loss of quality when stretching graphics

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

```html
<div
  className="CartLine"
  style={{
    display: "flex",
    position: "relative",
    boxShadow:
      "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 2px 1px -1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14) 0px 1px 1px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 1px 3px 0px",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  }}
>
  <Bar
    options={options}
    data={data}
    style={{
      minWidth: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      marginLeft: "auto",
      marginRight: "auto",
      marginTop: "auto",
      marginBottom: "auto",
    }}
  />
</div>
```

[image: chart]

I tried to set responsive in the options, but the graph loses quality.How to ensure that quality is not lost when resizing a chart?

Comment: Try following the guidelines from chart.js doc on [responsive charts](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html). My understanding of it for your case would be to remove all (size related) styling on the `Bar` component; and if the `div` gets resized as you wish, than it should be OK, otherwise try using `vw` and `vh`units if possible.

Comment: @kikon do you want to add an answer, or should this be closed as a simple typo?

Comment: how is that a typo?

Comment: @MikeSzyndel I think the question is legit, but my contribution is not precise enough to be an actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

Aftera more detailed study of the documentation on the advice
kikon, it became clear that the dimensions of the wrong solution were being transferred to convas. It is enough to set responsive options: true,
support AspectRatio: false and wrap the chart in a class with 100% width

Answer (score 0):

try to set the width and the height of the canvas

```
  <Bar
    options={options}
    data={data}
    style={{
      minWidth: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      marginLeft: "auto",
      marginRight: "auto",
      marginTop: "auto",
      marginBottom: "auto",
    }}
    width ={600}
    height={400}
  />
```